# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

this is the error i'm getting in my react application. please help me fix this. I've extended the code for better understanding. Have any idea what's the problem

```
const TextEditor = (value, props) => {
   console.log(props.value)
   console.log(props.value.length)
   const renderElement = useCallback(props => <Element {...props} />, [])
    const renderLeaf = useCallback(props => <Leaf {...props} />, [])
    const editor = useMemo(() => withHistory(withReact(createEditor())), [])
```

update-as told, I've added the code where i pass my values.
I've used value= {value.document} where I've initialised document in the initialValues below

```
 const TextEditor = (value, props) => {
      console.log(props.value)
      console.log(props.value.length)
      const renderElement = useCallback(props => <Element {...props} />, [])
      const renderLeaf = useCallback(props => <Leaf {...props} />, [])
      const editor = useMemo(() => withHistory(withReact(createEditor())), [])
      const [isPreviewModalOpen, setPreviewModal] = useState(false);
      
      const initialValues= {
        title:value.title,
        document: value.document,
      }
    
      return (
        <>
        
          <div className="text-center pt-3">
            <h2 style={{color: "#3D44C8", fontWeight: "bold"}}>Ask an expert</h2>
            <p style={{color: "#DB262F", fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "18px"}}>Get your questions solved within 24 hours!</p>
          </div>
          <Slate editor={editor} value={props.value} onChange={value => {
            props.setValue(value);}} >
            <div className="textEditor_toolbar">
              <div className="textEditor_buttonedit">
                <Navbar style={{padding: "0"}} expand="lg">
                  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                  <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                    <Navbar.Brand>
                      <ButtonGroup>
                        <MarkButton format="bold" tooltip="bold" icon={faBold}/>
                        <MarkButton format="italic" icon={faItalic} />
                        <MarkButton format="underline" icon={faUnderline} />
                      </ButtonGroup>
                      <ButtonGroup>
                        <MarkButton2 format="code" icon={faCode}/>
                        <BlockButton format="bulleted-list" icon={faListUl} />
                        <BlockButton format="numbered-list" icon={faListOl} />
                      </ButtonGroup>
                    </Navbar.Brand>     
                        <Nav>
                          <label className="custom-file-upload">
                            <input
                              type="file"
                              name="profileImg"
                              accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
                              multiple="false"
                              onChange={setImage}
                            />
                            <FontAwesomeIcon className="custom-file-icon" icon={faPaperclip}/>
                          </label>
                        </Nav>
                        <Form> 
                          <Choice  />
                        </Form>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                  </Navbar>
                  </div>
                </div>
              <div>
            </div>
            <Editable
              className="textEditorMain"
              renderElement={renderElement}
              renderLeaf={renderLeaf}
              value={value.document}
              placeholder="Type your Question, Paste your Question text or Attach images or PDF here"
              spellCheck
              autoFocus
              useReadOnly
              onPaste = {onPaste}
              onKeyPress={event => {
                for (const hotkey in HOTKEYS) {
                  if (isHotkey(hotkey, event )) {
                    event.preventDefault()
                    const mark = HOTKEYS[hotkey]
                    toggleMark(editor, mark)
                  }
                }
              }}
            />
          </Slate>
```

Comment: This error is saying that `props.value` does not exist. What do you expect `value` to be?

Comment: Add in the code where you pass the props if you want us to further help you

Comment: @Silidrone, I've added more info. Can you please look into it and help me out?

Comment: But where do you pass the props to `TextEditor` component, that's the code I need, where do you render the `TextEditor` component? The problem is probably outside the component, so the code you are showing doesn't help.

Comment: I have not rendered the TextEditor component, @Silidrone

Comment: What do you mean you haven't rendered it? How does the code ever reach there then? The error you are receiving indicates that in the props you have passed to TextEditor component (that is where you render it), you didnt pass value to it, so it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`props.value` is undefined, make sure you are correctly passing your props